# Is it possible to use destructuring assignment with "this" fields?

Tags: javascript, object, this, variable-assignment, destructuring

I have a function that changes two arguments and returns object

```
...
pos2pix = function (x, y) {
    return {
        xpx: x * cellBase * 1.5 + offsetX + x * paddingX,
        ypx: 2 * S3D2N * y + (x % 2 === 0 ? S_AD : 0) + offsetY + y * paddingY
    };
},
...
```

and a function, that uses this data:

```
...
Cell = function (x, y, ctx) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.highlighted = false;
    this.xpx = 0;
    this.ypx = 0;
    //error here
    {xpx: this.xpx, ypx: this.ypx} = pos2pix(x, y);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    //find neighbours
    this.nbhs = findNbhs(x, y);
};
...
```

what I want is to use destructuring assignment. I tried these attempts:

```
pos2pix = function (x, y) {
    return [
        x * cellBase * 1.5 + offsetX + x * paddingX,
        2 * S3D2N * y + (x % 2 === 0 ? S_AD : 0) + offsetY + y * paddingY
    ];
},
...
this.xpx = 0;
this.ypx = 0;
[this.xpx, this.ypx] = pos2pix(x, y);
```

this works fine. Also

```
var coords = pos2pix(x, y);
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.highlighted = false;
this.xpx = coords.xpx;
this.ypx = coords.ypx;
```

certainly works fine. Question is is it possible to use "this" in desructuring assignment with objects, and how to use it properly.

Comment: Not posible to JS, consider: `var tmp = pos2pix(...); this.xpx = tmp.xpx, ...` etc..

Comment: When you say *"this works fine"*, did you really check? I catch the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Comment: of course I did. Now my code works with destructuring assignment using array. I work with Firefox.

Comment: @IvanIvanov What I actually mean is that `[this.xpx, this.ypx] = pos2pix(x, y);` can't work in JavaScript.

Comment: Why not? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @sp00m it can in [es6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring)

Comment: @IvanIvanov Wow interesting, sorry, my fault! Never saw this in JS yet though :)

Comment: I'm wondering right now, why right code that will only work in a single browser? It may be supported by multiple browsers in the future, but this certainly breaks backwards compatibility.

Comment: I don't ask about right code. I will never use it in production. But this feature will be available in all browser a few years later. Why not to use it my projects?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I meant 'write code' of course. However, "a few years later" sounds like a long time, and as I said it won't be backwards compatible with then older browsers. So if you wish to support the Chinese market... Jokes.

Comment: A few years means 2016. I hope civilization will be alive at that time.

Comment: I suppose it will, haha. My thoughts are rather, though, that some people may simply not update their browser. However, let's just drop the thought. You probably know what you're doing. Back to topic: what do you mean by "this in destructuring assignment with objects"? As far as I can tell, everything works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqo36rtp/2/).

Comment: In link mentioned above there is a "named arguments" feature and destructuring assignment using array. Array d.a. works fine, but I need object destructuring bind. I have plethora of functions that return {x: a, y: b, ...}, and want to assign fields of my "class" using this functions in one line. All objects in my projects interact using objects, not arrays.

Comment: @Derija93 In addition to the fact that many ES6 features like destructuring will likely be in other browsers sooner than later, you can easily use them now if you include a transpiler such as [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [es6-transpiler](https://github.com/termi/es6-transpiler) in your build process.

Comment: Although I've understood your issue now, tbh I cannot manage to work out the syntax error I get from the [object destructuring](http://jsfiddle.net/mqo36rtp/7/). I suppose I won't be a lot of help in this regard. Good luck though!